# Dynamic importing of modules followed by instantiation of objects with a certain baseclass from said modules

Tags: python, plugins

I'm writing an application. No fancy GUI:s or anything, just a plain old console application. This application, lets call it App, needs to be able to load plugins on startup. So, naturally, i created a class for the plugins to inherit from:

```
class PluginBase(object):
    def on_load(self):
        pass
    def on_unload(self):
        pass
    def do_work(self, data):
        pass
```

The idea being that on startup, App would walk through the current dir, including subdirs, searching for modules containing classes that themselves are subclasses of `PluginBase`.

More code:

```
class PluginLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, path, cls):
        """ path=path to search (unused atm), cls=baseclass """
        self.path=path
    def search(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
            candidates = [fname for fname in files if fname.endswith('.py') \
                                    and not fname.startswith('__')]
        ## this only works if the modules happen to be in the current working dir
        ## that is not important now, i'll fix that later
        if candidates:
            basename = os.path.split(os.getcwd())[1]
            for c in candidates:
                modname = os.path.splitext(c)[0]
                modname = '{0}.{1}'.format(basename, modname)
                __import__(mod)
                module = sys.modules[mod]
```

After that last line in `search` I'd like to somehow a) find all classes in the newly loaded module, b) check if one or more of those classes are subclasses of `PluginBase` and c) (if b) instantiate that/those classes and add to App's list of loaded modules.

I've tried various combinations of `issubclass` and others, followed by a period of intense `dir`:ing and about an hour of panicked googling. I did find a similar approach to mine [here](http://www.luckydonkey.com/2008/01/02/python-style-plugins-made-easy/) and I tried just copy-pasting that but got an error saying that Python doesn't support imports by filename, at which point I kind of lost my concentration and as a result of that, this post was written.

I'm at my wits end here, all help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might do something like this:

```
for c in candidates:
    modname = os.path.splitext(c)[0]
    try:
        module=__import__(modname)   #<-- You can get the module this way
    except (ImportError,NotImplementedError):
        continue
    for cls in dir(module):          #<-- Loop over all objects in the module's namespace
        cls=getattr(module,cls)
        if (inspect.isclass(cls)                # Make sure it is a class 
            and inspect.getmodule(cls)==module  # Make sure it was defined in module, not just imported
            and issubclass(cls,base)):          # Make sure it is a subclass of base
            # print('found in {f}: {c}'.format(f=module.__name__,c=cls))
            classList.append(cls)
```

To test the above, I had to modify your code a bit; below is the full script.

```
import sys
import inspect
import os

class PluginBase(object): pass

def search(base):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        candidates = [fname for fname in files if fname.endswith('.py') 
                      and not fname.startswith('__')]
        classList=[]
        if candidates:
            for c in candidates:
                modname = os.path.splitext(c)[0]
                try:
                    module=__import__(modname)
                except (ImportError,NotImplementedError):
                    continue
                for cls in dir(module):
                    cls=getattr(module,cls)
                    if (inspect.isclass(cls)
                        and inspect.getmodule(cls)==module
                        and issubclass(cls,base)):
                        # print('found in {f}: {c}'.format(f=module.__name__,c=cls))
                        classList.append(cls)
        print(classList)

search(PluginBase)
```

Comment: It worked almost perfectly, thank you! I added `and cls.__name__ != base.__name__` to avoid the base class being added to the list of subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

You would make this a lot easier if you forced some constraints on the plugin writer, for example that all plugins must be packages that contain a `load_plugin( app, config)` function that returns a Plugin instance. Then all you have to do is try to import these packages and run the function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a meta-classier way to register the plugins:

Define `PluginBase` to be of type `PluginType`.
`PluginType` automatically registers any instance (class) in the `plugins` set.

**plugin.py:**

```
plugins=set()
class PluginType(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super(PluginType, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        # print(cls, name,cls.__module__)
        plugins.add(cls)

class PluginBase(object):
    __metaclass__=PluginType
    pass
```

This is the part that the user writes. Notice that there is nothing special here.

**pluginDir/myplugin.py:**

```
import plugin
class Foo(plugin.PluginBase):
    pass
```

Here is what the search function might look like:

**test.py:**

```
import plugin
import os
import imp

def search(plugindir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(plugindir):
        for fname in files:
            modname = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
            try:
                module=imp.load_source(modname,os.path.join(root,fname))
            except Exception: continue

search('pluginDir')
print(plugin.plugins)
```

Running test.py yields

```
set([<class 'myplugin.Foo'>])
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use execfile() instead of import with a specified namespace dict, then iterate over that namespace with issubclass, etc?